# Unity 2D Bullet AddForce does not work

Tags: unity, rigidbody

I got the following code :

```
public ParticleSystem PS;
public GameObject origin;
public float thrust = 1.0f;
public GameObject bullet;
private GameObject _bullet;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Pressed left click.");
        PS.Play();
        _bullet = Instantiate(bullet, origin.transform.position, origin.transform.rotation);
        _bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(origin.transform.forward * thrust);
    }
}
```

Where everything is working except the AddForce, the bullet is just dropping out of my weapon. I've made some research and my script seems to be correct. The bullet has attached a circle collider and a rigidbody2D.

Update: This did not change anything :

```
_bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(origin.transform.forward * thrust, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

And this neither :

```
_bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = origin.transform.forward * thrust;
```

It's weird, because all of these should work actually.

Comment: Adding a force is good for acceleration over time, like a rocket engine burning or a magnet pulling. For firing a bullet you usually want something more instantaneous, like setting the velocity directly or applying an impulse. Have you tried this?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: It could just be that your thrust is too low, or that the object is hitting something immediately that's sapping its momentum, or that there's another script in your project that's also trying to control the bullet and overriding this effect...

Comment: Thrust is on 10000 and there is no collider in range which could block it and just one script is using this :( It must be some stupid simple little thing I'm missing :/

Comment: By any chance did you tick the "Is Kinematic" setting on your bullet's Rigidbody2D? This will signal to the physics engine "don't integrate forces and velocities on this body, I intend to position it manually each frame." Also double-check that you haven't enabled any constraints on its motion or jointed it to anything, and that its drag is low/zero.

Comment: Did that. The bullets are dropping so they are affected by gravity and I can "shoot" them around when I walk against them. Well I guess I have to figure out what I messed up by myself, but thanks a lot for double checking my scripts :)

Comment: A 2D Game with transform.forward is not the best idea.... For sure transform.right is fixing the problem

Comment: Oh gosh, I can't believe I missed that you were using transform.forward, which usually points along z, instead of an xy vector in the 2D physics plane. Good catch! Consider writing up that note as an answer and marking it accepted (after a delay) — that way it's easier for people with similar issues to find & learn from your experience.

Comment: Yeah it took me way to long to realise this issue... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just a minor mistake in this code which is `transform.forward`, which points to the z-axis which is obviously not working in a 2D game. So instead of this :

```
_bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(origin.transform.forward * thrust);
```

use this and it should work just fine :

```
_bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(origin.transform.right * thrust);
```

But at least the question is now a good summary of possible ways to give your object some speed. ( Force, velocity...)